# R - return boolean if any strings in a vector appear in any of several columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, apply, grepl

I have a large data frame, each row of which refers to an admission to hospital. Each admission is accompanied by up to 20 diagnosis codes in columns 5 to 24.

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3 ... Diag_20
data   data   data   data   J123    F456    H789       E468
data   data   data   data   T452    NA      NA         NA
```

Separately, I have a vector (*risk_codes*) of length 136, all strings. These strings are risk codes that can be similar to the truncated diagnosis codes (e.g. J12 would be ok, F4 would be ok, H798 would not).

I wish to add a column to the data frame that returns 1 if **any** of the risk codes are similar to any of the diagnosis codes. I don't need to know how many, just that at least one is.

So far, I've tried the following with the most success over other attempts:

```
for (in in 1:length(risk_codes){
    df$newcol <- apply(df,1,function(x) sum(grepl(risk_codes[i], x[c(5:24)])))
}
```

It works well for a single string and populates the column with 0 for no similar codes and 1 for a similar code, but then everything is overwritten when the second code is checked, and so on over the 136 elements of the risk_codes vector.

Any ideas, please? Running a loop over every risk_code in every column for every row would not be feasible.

The solution would look like this

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3 ... Diag_20   newcol
data   data   data   data   J123    F456    H789       E468      1
data   data   data   data   T452    NA      NA         NA        0
```

if my risk_codes contained J12, F4, T543, for example.

Comment: I submitted an answer, but now after rereading the question, im unsure I understood correctly. Do you want the 1 in the new col, when there is a perfect match between risk_code and Diag_ or it is also 1, if there is a partial match. eg: J123 and J1 should have 1 in the end?

Comment: Partial matches. If J123 is a diagnosis code in the data frame, then risk_codes of J123, J12 and J1 should all return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to apply the grepl with all the risk_codes at once. So we get one result per row at once. We can do that with `sapply` and `any`.

So, we can drop the for loop and your code becomes like this:

```
my_df <- read.table(text="Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3  Diag_20
data   data   data   data   J123    F456    H789       E468
data   data   data   data   T452    NA      NA         NA", header=TRUE)

risk_codes <- c("F456", "XXX") # test codes

my_df$newcol <- apply(my_df,1,function(x) 
                                  any(sapply(risk_codes, 
                                              function(codes) grepl(codes,
                                                              x[c(5:24)]))))
```

The result is a logical vector.

If you still want to use 1 and 0 instead of the TRUE/FALSE, you just need to finish with:

```
my_df$new_col <- ifelse(my_df$newcol, 1, 0)
```

The result will be:

```
> my_df
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Diag_1 Diag_2 Diag_3 Diag_20 newcol
1 data data data data   J123   F456   H789    E468      1
2 data data data data   T452   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>      0
```

Comment: Thank you, that would identify a lot of relevant records. 

But would it, for example, return a 1 in the new column if the vector of risk_codes consisted of c("F45", "XXX")?

The grepl function permits that, if searching for strings one by one. I would need "F45" to be a successful result of the search, as a code of F45 is a sub-set of the F456 in the data frame.

Comment: I had misinterpreted the question. Now I updated the answer. basically i'm replacing your outer for loop with an sapply call inside the function(x).

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you very much indeed! I need to go over some notes on the apply and sapply functions, clearly!

Comment: Try using `sum` instead of `any`. It should count the number of TRUE values.