# R - Count the number of times similar strings appear in several columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, apply, grepl

Following from an earlier problem:  [R - return boolean if any strings in a vector appear in any of several columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936658/r-return-boolean-if-any-strings-in-a-vector-appear-in-any-of-several-columns)

I didn't think I needed to count the number of similar strings from my vector that appear in my data frame, but it turns out it's useful information. D'oh!

**The problem**:
I have a large data frame of which columns 5 to 24 are diagnosis codes. Each row is an individual admission to hospital. The vector *risk_codes* contains truncated diagnosis codes. I sought a new column to the data frame that told me if any risk_codes appeared in the 20 diagnosis codes. The catch was that I needed a partial match, not full match.

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3 ... Diag_20
data   data   data   data   J123    F456    H789       E468
data   data   data   data   T452    NA      NA         NA
```

**The code to do that**:

```
df$newcol <- apply(df,1,function(x) any(sapply(risk_codes, function(codes) grepl(codes,x[c(5:24)]))))
df$newcol <- ifelse(df$newcol,1,0)
```

This successfully returns 1 to the new column if any risk_codes match the admission's diagnosis codes.

```
risk_codes <- c("J1","F45","H987")

Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3 ... Diag_20   newcol
data   data   data   data   J123    F456    H789       E468      1
data   data   data   data   T452    NA      NA         NA        0
```

**The additional complication**: Now I'd like to count the number of matches, rather than just see that there are matches. It's likely a manipulation of the first line of code presented but I'm struggling to find the logic.

```
risk_codes <- c("J1","F45","H987")

Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Diag_1  Diag_2  Diag_3 ... Diag_20  newcol  count
data   data   data   data   J123    F456    H789       E468     1       2
data   data   data   data   T452    NA      NA         NA       0       0
```

Comment: You should include a [reproducible example]() in your question with sample input and the desired output for that input. It's odd that you list a "solution" in your own question. Maybe you can make it more clear that's not actually what you are after.

Comment: Good point, sorry.

Comment: I think you mean to say that columns 5-24 are dx codes. Otherwise the code could not possibly be delivering useful results.

Comment: *columns* 5-24, indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption that you are referring to columns rather than rows, then this should succeed:

```
df$code_count <- apply(df,1,function(x) 
                         sum(sapply(risk_codes, function(codes) grepl(codes,x[c(5:24)]))))
```

Comment: Goodness me! Thank you, though I'm a little frustrated that I didn't spot that myself.